# URI segment can't be saved in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert a new record in a database table. The function that does the insert is this:

```
public function comment($id_b,$comment){
$id_u = $this->session->userdata('userid');
$result=$this->db->insert('comments',['id_book'=>$id_b, 'id_user'=>$id_u, 'comment'=>$comment] );
return $result;
}
```

The controller function where `comment`  is called:

```
public function comment()
{
$this->load->model('model');
$id_b= $this->uri->segment('3');
$comment=$this->input->post('comment');
$this->model->comment($id_b,$comment);
}
```

The uri segment I'm trying to get is an `id`. The problem is that it can't be saved in database, it always has the value `NULL`.

I tried `echo $this->uri->segment('3');` and it actually returns the id, but I don't understand why it is saved as `NULL` value in database.

When I tried this: `(int)$this->uri->segment('3');` , I got this error:

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_book`) REFERENCES `book` (`id_book`))

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id_book`, `id_user`, `comments`) VALUES (0, '5', 'test')

So, it tries to insert a book with `id_book=0` when in fact there is no such record in the book table and I have no idea where it gets the `id_book=0` because  `$this->uri->segment(3)` returns 1.

Comment: `$this->uri->segment(3);` should be integer, check if it changes something?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 you're saying I should convert `$this->uri->segment(3)` to integer?

Comment: what's the php version?  only after php 5.4 you can use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

Comment: @Vickel php version->5.6.14

Comment: @eri you should enter 3 as integer not as '3' which means string, and can be interpreted as 1 or even true :)

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 it doesn't make any difference :/

Comment: and how does your path looks like /some-post/comment/233 , do you have any specific route for it?

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 my path is something like this: http://localhost/project/index.php/search_results/result/1

Comment: check your field in mysql, maybe the order is different, or data type , just shooting

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 nope, they're the same

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: It's hard to guess. My last idea would be, that naming model a "model" does something with escaping input. @wolfgang1983 I know that part already, the logic seems ok,it has to be some oversight

Comment: @eri I think you should rename your model. to exmple Blog_model http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: I renamed the model and it doesn't make any difference

Comment: after your edit: please have a look at these results: https://www.google.pt/search?q=+a+foreign+key+constraint+fails&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YQ2aWYfcJJHY8gfX35uwDg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution, and that's to get your `$id_b` value from the parameter of the controller method that was routed to. Based on your comments above, it appears that your URI string is search_results/result/1. That means you are routing to the result method, in the search_results controller. `$id_b` is 1.

In the Search_results.php controller:

```
/**
 * Result
 * @param  int $id_b
 */
public function result( $id_b )
{
    // Pass $id_b to the comment method
    // or whatever method calls the comment method
    $this->comment( $id_b );
}

/**
 * Comment
 * @param  int $id_b
 */
public function comment( $id_b )
{
    $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
    $this->load->model('model');

    // Continue passing $id_b to the model
    $this->model->comment( $id_b, $comment );
}
```

The code in your model can mostly remain the same.

```
/**
 * Comment
 * @param  int $id_b
 * @param  string $comment
 */
public function comment( $id_b, $comment )
{
    $id_u = $this->session->userdata('userid');

    return $this->db->insert('comments',[
        'id_book' => $id_b, 
        'id_user' => $id_u, 
        'comment' => $comment
    ]);
}
```

I can't tell you why you are having problems getting the 3rd segment of the URI with `$this->uri->segment(3)`, but hopefully this work-around allows you to continue.

If it were me, in order to fix the URI segment issue, I would expirament with changing the config value for uri_protocol in /application/config/config.php. While you're there, make sure you are setting a valid base_url. In past versions, you did not have to set a base_url, but CodeIgniter says this is now mandatory. I've been working with CodeIgniter since v1.7.2 (2009), and never seen a problem with URI segments. If my advice doesn't point you in the right direction, I suggest sharing some information about your CodeIgniter config.php file, and your server.